# Cypress input how to get to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, cypress

I have something like this:

`<input aria-invalid="false" type="number" min="1" class="MuiInputBase-input-1102 MuiInput-input-1141" value="1">`[image]

how to get to it ??

Comment: can you explain your problem more and add some code?

Comment: what do you mean by how to get there? what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the button Open Selector Playground. Then you can simply click on the input field and you get the code on how to "get" it.

[image]

This will appear and on the right site of the window you can directly copy the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click element and click **Copy** > **Copy Selector**

In your test:

```
cy.get('Selector')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab an element by id, class, or other HTML attributes. So a few potential options would be:

- cy.get('input[aria-invalid="false"]')
- cy.get('input[type="number"]')
- cy.get('.MuiInputBase-input-1102)